# Outputting JSP values into JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript, jsp

Ok - so I have written this code to output values using JSP and set them as JS variables so I can pass them to my Google Analytics tracking code.

```
<dsp:droplet name="/atg/dynamo/droplet/ForEach">
            <dsp:param value="${CommerceItems}" name="array" />
            <dsp:param name="elementName" value="CommerceItem" />
            <dsp:oparam name="outputStart">var itemCatList ='</dsp:oparam>
            <dsp:oparam name="output"
                <dsp:getvalueof id="Category"param="CommerceItem.auxiliaryData.productRef.productWebType.productWebTypeDescription">${Category}|</dsp:getvalueof>
            </dsp:oparam>
            <dsp:oparam name="outputEnd">'; </dsp:oparam>
        </dsp:droplet>
```

Im not sure if this is the correct way to go about doing this - previously the values were set to hidden inputs - then JS is used to grab those values out. I was trying to eliminate the extra code.

Any issues with doing it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, although opinion is mixed on what the best way to expose variables into JS is.

I find the above non-obvious and difficult to read, however. If there was a way to consume JSON I might prefer that as opposed to building a pipe-delimited string, or I would wrap it up in a custom tag that abstracted all of this away so a casual reader wouldn't have to do any mental gymnastics.

Another option would be to build the delimited string in Java code and expose it directly.